# Inverting large JSON dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

I have a JSON dictionary containing multiple entries (roughly 8 million) of the following form:

```
{"Some_String": {"Name0": 1, "Name1": 1, "Name42": 2, "Name5": 2, ... }, ...}
```

It contains strings that have been used to reference discrete named entities along with counts of how many times that name has been referenced by that string.

I want to invert the mapping so that the Name0 is followed by the strings that have referenced it (maintaining the counts). A name is likely to appear within multiple string entries.

```
{"Name0": {"Some_String": 1, "Some_other_string": 1,... }, ...}
```

My question is: is there some JSON functionality that will allow me to efficiently do this?

My naive approach involves adding each name into a 2D array (adding the strings and counts to that array as they are found).

Initially this ran quite quickly, but as the size of the array increases the running time decreases (linear search).

```
for string in list(surface.keys()):

    for count, name in zip(surfacs[string].values(),surface[string].keys()):

        if name in pages:
            surface_count_list[pages.index(name)].append([string, count])


        else:
            pages.append(name)
            surface_count_list.append([string, count])
```

I realise I could add this data directly into a new dictionary, but I didn't know if this would really increase the efficiency of adding new items as the size of the dictionary increases.

Thanks.

Comment: This would be a perfect situation to put your JSON data into a relational database.

Comment: JSON is just a serialization format, a way to describe data as text. There really isn't any "JSON functionality" to change data.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @Tomalak thanks, will look into making it into a database.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich python 3. I thought there probably was not some functionality for it as I did look myself, I was hoping there might be some more pythonic way of doing what I had attempted that would be more efficient.

Comment: @Lee don't bother with those fancy nosql databases. Use a proper RDBMS, whatever you have available (SQLite is worth a look if you want something self-contained and deployable, full-blown systems might offer better performance). Set up three tables: word, string, word_to_string.

Comment: @Tomolak: a single table word, name, count would work? With indexes on the first two.

Comment: @Remco If it's a strict 1:n relation, yes. I don't know enouh about the OP's data; the three table setup would cover 1:n and m:n as well, and it supports forward and reverse queries with the same ease.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(dict)

for somestring, namesdict in initialdata.items():
    for name, amount in namesdict.items():
        result[name][something] = amount
```

Would do it, but with 8 million items it may become time to look at databases.

Comment: Thanks- I will probably look into databases.